# Swift: DispatchGroup notify called before task finish

Tags: swift, multithreading

Why is dispatchGroup.notify being called before my stocks loop? Shouldn't it be called only after the task is done? Below is an image of my console to show you what I mean.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     fetch { (stocks) in
        self.hud.dismiss()

          APIManager.shareInstance.getStockList(for: self.fetchedStocks) { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let stocks):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.fetchedStocks = stocks
                    print(self.fetchedStocks)
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print("Couldn't find Symbol")
                print(error.localizedDescription)

            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Reload data")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `dispatchGroup.enter()` before `getStockList`, not inside the closure.

You also need to move the `dispatchGroup.leave` outside the `stocks.forEach`:

```
fetch { stocks in
    self.hud.dismiss()

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    APIManager.shareInstance.getStockList(for: self.fetchedStocks) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let stocks):
            stocks.forEach { stock in
                for index in 0..<stocks.count {
                    self.fetchedStocks[index] = stock
                    print("Stock Model:", self.fetchedStocks[index])
                }
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Sucessfully retrieve necessary data, now reloading tableview")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, since it appears that `getStockList` is called only once, you can eliminate the dispatch group entirely:

```
fetch { stocks in
    self.hud.dismiss()

    APIManager.shareInstance.getStockList(for: self.fetchedStocks) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let stocks):
            stocks.forEach { (stock) in
                for index in 0..<stocks.count {
                    self.fetchedStocks[index] = stock
                    print("Stock Model:", self.fetchedStocks[index])
                }
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("Now reloading tableview")
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Note, the `DispatchQueue.main.async` isn’t needed if `fetch` calls this closure on the main queue already. And if it’s not calling it on the main queue, then you probably want to dispatch the updating of `self.fetchedStocks` to the main queue, as well, to ensure thread safety of this model object.

---

I’m not sure why you’re iterating through `stocks`. I would have thought that this would be sufficient:

```
fetch { stocks in
    self.hud.dismiss()

    APIManager.shareInstance.getStockList(for: self.fetchedStocks) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let stocks):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.fetchedStocks = stocks
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Again, that `DispatchQueue.main.async` isn’t needed if the `fetch` completion handler already runs on the main queue.

Comment: Thank you! yea answer was so simple, I didn't need to iterate through array! Setting reloadData within the Dispatch only brings me back 1 element with the correct price per stock. I'm expecting 4 elements. But when I put it at the end of "fetch" I get the correct 4 elements but no price.

Comment: There’s obviously something else going on, but it undoubtedly depends upon the implementation of `fetch` and `getStockList` something we can’t comment on without seeing those routines. That seems like a different question to me. This question seemed to be about the correct use of dispatch group, which I believe I’ve answered.

Comment: thank you, you've helped a lot! ill dive deeper into it.